# How do I write a doctest in python 3.5 for a function using random to replace characters in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def intoxication(text):
    """This function causes each character to have a 1/5 chance of being replaced by a random letter from the string of letters
    INSERT DOCTEST HERE
    """
    import random
    string_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    text = "".join(i if random.randint(0,4) else random.choice(string_letters) for i in text)   

    return text
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock the random functions to give something that is predetermined.

```
def intoxication(text):
    """This function causes each character to have a 1/5 chance of being replaced by a random letter from the string of letters

    If there is 0% chance of a random character chosen, result will be the same as input
    >>> import random
    >>> myrand = lambda x, y: 1
    >>> mychoice = lambda x: "T"
    >>> random.randint = myrand
    >>> random.choice = mychoice
    >>> intoxication("Hello World")
    'Hello World'

    If there is 100% chance of a random character chosen, result will be the same as 'TTTTTTTTTTT'
    >>> import random
    >>> myrand = lambda x, y: 0
    >>> mychoice = lambda x: "T"
    >>> random.randint = myrand
    >>> random.choice = mychoice
    >>> intoxication("Hello World")
    'TTTTTTTTTTT'

    If every second character is replaced
    >>> import random
    >>> thisone = 0
    >>> def myrand(x, y): global thisone; thisone+=1; return thisone % 2
    >>> mychoice = lambda x: "T"
    >>> random.randint = myrand
    >>> random.choice = mychoice
    >>> intoxication("Hello World")
    'HTlToTWTrTd'

    If every third character is replaced
    >>> import random
    >>> thisone = 0
    >>> def myrand(x, y): global thisone; thisone+=1; return thisone % 3
    >>> mychoice = lambda x: "T"
    >>> random.randint = myrand
    >>> random.choice = mychoice
    >>> intoxication("Hello World")
    'HeTloTWoTld'

    """
    import random
    string_letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    text = "".join(i if random.randint(0,4) else random.choice(string_letters) for i in text)   

    return text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```